# "must be connected to terminal" when using Remote SSH in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I was getting this error while trying to connect VSCode to a raspberry pi
Tweaking lots of settings within VSCode did nothing to help.
What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that, in my case at least, this is actually nothing to do with VSCode itself, but the SSH key I was using was configured to start or connect to a gnu screen session.

Check your authorized_keys file and see if the SSH key is configured to run a specific command, this prevents VSCode from being able to issue the commands it needs.

Either remove this restriction or configure a second key.